# RabbitMQ Enabled Management plugin without having website enabled

Tags: installation, rabbitmq

I'm using some aspects of the RabbitMQ management plugin in my start up config to load queue/exchanges from a .json when a server is restarted for whatever reason.

However I don't want the website portion for the plugin enabled.

*mochiweb

*webmachine

*rabbitmq_web_dispatch

Whenever I try to individually disable any of the above it also disabled the management plugin.

I know there are alternatives to using the very convenient .json file concept for creating static exchanges/queues/mappings at start-up.   I'd just like to be lazy.  We'd prefer to not having our rabbit servers have the web plugins enabled.

(ie On a workstation using the website management tool to create exchanges and mappings and queues and exporting the .json file, and then copying it to a server that using the start-up config setting to load from said .json file.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of disabling the web partition without breaking the plugin, at least not without modifying the source code. If you want to disable this for security reasons, you could simply change the listening binding to be limited to the localhost.

```
[{rabbitmq_management,
  [{listener, [{port, 15672},
               {ip, "127.0.0.1"}
              ]}
  ]}
].
```

This way the Management plugin is only reachable on localhost.